# Swift exit IBAction func in if

Tags: ios, swift, function, exit

Im trying to end a funtion of an IBAction in an if statement, after validation input.

I've made a (global) function to check if the values of the variables which contain user input are Integers. Im trying to exit the functon by returning nothing, but the function doesn't end.

```
@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
var objects: [Int?] = [] // Contains an array of variables to be checked

    //Global.checkInt returns true if all the variables in the array are int
    //Global.throwLocalNot Global function to show a local notification

    if Global.checkInt(objects) == false{
        Global.throwLocalNot("Error", description: "Check your input!", viewController: self)
        return
    }

// Code to be executed if all variables are integers
...
}
```

This code works and throws a local notification if the input is not correct, but the return does not seem to work. What is the best way to stop a function from further execution?

Comment: Your code looks correct to me, and the `return` should be sufficient to exit your `IBAction` method. What are you seeing that makes you think it is not working?

Comment: I've added an println statement after the IF block that writes a message in the terminal. Then I tried entering false input, I do get the message but the code after the if block will be exectued. The println message will appear in the terminal and the app crashes due to fault input.

Comment: The objects array is empty. Where do you add values to it? Also, can you post the code for your checkInt method?

Comment: I've removed the declaration of the variables. The array is filled with variables which contain the value of a text field. For example:
var windSpeed = WindspeedField.text.toInt()
Then these variables are added to the array.
For the checkInt:
for object in objects{
            if object == nil{
                return false
            }
        }
        return true

This code is all working, I do get the notification triggered within the if statement, but the code thereafter is executed, however the Calculate function should be stopped by the return.